# Encode UTF-8 for list

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I'm using selenium to retrieve a list from a javascript object.

```
search_reply = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ac_results")
```

When trying to write to csv, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insref_lookup15.py", line 54, in <module>
    wr_insref.writerow(instrument_name)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried placing .encode("utf-8") on both:

```
search_reply = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ac_results").encode("utf-8")
```

and

```
wr_insref.writerow(instrument_name).encode("utf-8")
```

but I just get the message

```
AttributeError: 'xxx' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: what does `driver.find_element_by_class_name` return? is it a list? is it a class? what I can infer that it's not a string, for sure.

Comment: @Winterflags: and in that list are only string objects? Presumably printing it gives something like `[u'foo', u'bar',...]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I get [u'foo', u'bar',...].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the *elements in the list*:

```
wr_insref.writerow([v.encode('utf8') for v in instrument_name])
```

The `csv` module documentation has an [*Examples* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) that covers writing Unicode objects in more detail, including utility classes to handle this automatically.